# Action when installing a plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress there are actions that are fired when we activate and/or deactivate plugins (activated_plugin, deactivated_plugin). Is there any action that is fired when we install some new plugin?

Comment: do you refer to plugins other than yours?

Comment: all plugins avible

Comment: Installing a plugin could be done even via FTP. There's no hook that can save you from that. At worst you have to write some cronjob that periodically checks for new folders inside the wp-content/plugins dir. If you instead mean the backend uploader i don't know

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any action you can hook into while a plugin is being installed, but there are a few filters.

1. apply_filters( 'plugins_api_args', $args, $action );
2. apply_filters( 'plugins_api', false, $action, $args );
3. apply_filters( 'plugins_api_result', $res, $action, $args );

This is the function that handles the ajax plugin install request [wp_ajax_install_plugin](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/dbc8d76a9f0fb15bd5546ce5d4dd78a8f497ae2f/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php#L4336)

The filters are located inside the [plugins_api](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/dbc8d76a9f0fb15bd5546ce5d4dd78a8f497ae2f/wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php#L102)

Hope this gives you enough tools to run the code that you want